# Display last body message on messaging system from scratch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, message, messaging

I made a messaging system from scractch on my App. All works good but i just want to customize more. So I want to display the last message for each Conversation by user_id inbox in my view . I have 2 models : Conversation and Message.

I can display only this

I m lost. Can you help me ?

messages_controller.rb

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
 before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action do
   @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
  end
def index

 @messages = @conversation.messages
  if @messages.length > 10
   @over_ten = true
   @messages = @messages[-10..-1]
  end
  if params[:m]
   @over_ten = false
   @messages = @conversation.messages
  end
 if @messages.last
  if @messages.last.user_id != current_user.id
   @messages.last.read = true;
  end
 end
@message = @conversation.messages.new
 end

private
 def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:body, :user_id)
 end
end
```

Conversations_controller.rb

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /conversations
  # GET /conversations.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @camping = Camping.all

    # Restrict to conversations with at least one message and sort by last updated
    @conversations = Conversation.joins(:messages).distinct


  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def conversation_params
      params.require(:conversation).permit(:sender_id, :recipient_id, :user_id)
    end
end
```

conversation.rb

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
 belongs_to :recipient, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'

 belongs_to :user
  has_many :users, through: :messages


has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy



validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, :scope => :recipient_id
scope :between, -> (sender_id,recipient_id) do
 where("(conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?) OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?)", sender_id,recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
 end


end
```

message.rb

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :conversation
 belongs_to :user

 validates_presence_of :body, :conversation_id, :user_id
```

/messages/index.html.erb

```
 <% @messages.each do |message| %>
  <% if message.body %>

   <% user = User.find(message.user_id) %>

<%= image_tag user.avatar(:thumb), class:"imageavatarmessage" %></div>
<%= user.prenom %>
      <%= message.message_time %>
      <div class="list">
         <%= message.body %>
          <% end %>
         <% end %>

<%= form_for [@conversation, @message], html: {class: "ui reply form"} do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control" %>
 </div>
 <%= f.text_field :user_id, value: current_user.id, type: "hidden" %>
   <%= f.submit "Add Reply", class: "ui blue labeled submit icon button" %>
<% end %>
```

Probleme is here, i just want to show last message for each conversation.
/conversations/index.html.erb

```
   <% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>
   <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id || conversation.recipient_id == current_user.id %>
    <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id %>
      <% recipient = User.find(conversation.recipient_id) %>

    <% else %>
      <% recipient = User.find(conversation.sender_id) %>

    <% end %>

    <p>Conversation avec <%= link_to recipient.prenom, conversation_messages_path(conversation)%></p>
    <p><%= image_tag recipient.avatar(:small), class:"imageavatarmessage" %></p>


   <%= @conversations.last %>


    <p>Il y a <%= time_ago_in_words(conversation.updated_at)%></p>


   <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

I want to display only the last one message for each conversations in my /conversations/index.html.erb I tested this <%= @conversations.last %> but it doesn't work...

Can you help me ?

### EDIT

My messages table

```
:body
:conversation, index: true
:user, index: true
:read, :default => false
t.timestamps
```

conversations table

```
   :sender_id
  :recipient_id
   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```

### EDIT 2

After some test I can display last message. But this message is the same for all conversation... I can't have last message for each conversation. I don't know why...

Conversation_controller

```
 @conversa = Conversation.where("? IN (recipient_id, sender_id)", current_user.id)
     @test = Message.where(conversation_id: @conversa).group(:conversation_id).limit(1)
```

in my /conversations/index.html.erb

```
<% @test.each do |message| %>

       <%= message.body %>

 <%end%>
```

I think that, I m near the solution, can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your current_user can directly reference the related conversations they are in you can setup your @conversations variable like this

```
def index
  ...
  @conversations = current_user.conversations.joins(:messages)
end
```

Once that is setup you can iterate over it with each one in your index view

```
<% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>
  <div>
    Last Message for Conversation ID:<%= conversation.id %> 
    is <%= conversation.messages.last.body %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Best answer ! Work like a charm :) Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Use .count instead of .length.

```
@messages = @conversation.messages
if @messages.count > 10
@over_ten = true
@messages = @messages[-10..-1]
end
```

Or you can do something like:

```
def index    
@messages = Messages.all.order("created_at DESC").limit(10)
end
```

Comment: Why not but my question is : display last message on conversation view ?

Comment: You mean the area where you loop through all conversations? Like in Facebook Messenger?

Comment: In my conversation.rb => has_many :users, through: :messages I want something like facebook.com/messages/ (left sidebar). So i need to display last message in conversation index but only the last.

Comment: Use ruby .last?

<%= @message.message.last[:message] %>

Comment: I have this result => NoMethodError in Conversations#index // undefined method `message' for nil:NilClass :(

Comment: Do .limit(1) uthe action where you want to ouput the message. 

in conversations controller
`code` def index
@messages = Messages.all.order("created_at DESC").limit(1)
end `code`

And then just `code`<% @message.message %>`code` in your view.

Comment: The same error => NoMethodError in Conversations#index => undefined method `message' for #<Message::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f9f2e574368>

Comment: Yes, but you need to call it in the conversations controller not in the messages controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128009/discussion-between-crashtor-and-nicolaswecandoit).

Comment: If I m doing this =>  <% @messages.each do |message| %>
   <%= message.body %>
   <%end%>
     I have the last message but not last message for specific user. I have only the last message and message is the same....

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who would want to have conversations list with last messages:
Here is the solution--- I have done in Rails 5.2.6 and via API I am using Serializer to formart JSON to get better attributes.

```rb
def conversations_list(user)
 @user= User.find(@user_id)  
 ids = Message.select("MAX(id) AS id")
       .group(:conversation_id).collect(&:id)
 @result = Message.order("created_at DESC").where(:id => ids)
           .joins(:conversation).order(id: :desc)
           .where("sender_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?", user.id, user.id)
           .paginate(page: params[:page],per_page:10)
    
 if @conversations.present?
  render json: {
   success: true, 
   result: ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(@result, each_serializer: ConversationSerializer),
  }
 else 
  @conversations= []
  render json: {
   success: true, 
   result: ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(@conversations, 
         each_serializer: ConversationSerializer),
     #micros: ActiveModel::Serializesr::CollectionSerializer.new(@micros, 
 each_serializer: MicroSerializer),
  }

 end 
end
```

Models

```rb
# conversation.rb
  has_many :messages
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :sender, :foreign_key => :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
       belongs_to :recipient, :foreign_key => :recipient_id, class_name: 
       'User'
  has_one :last_message, -> { order(created_at: :DESC) },class_name: 
 "Message"

  scope :between, -> (sender_id, recipient_id) do
    where("(conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id = ?) OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id = ?)", sender_id, recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
  end
end 

# Message.rb
   belongs_to :conversation
   belong_to :user
   validates_presence_of :body, :conversation_id, :user_id
end
```

Comment: Thanks Lam Phan for arranging this well for me.